# SqlGeometry in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, sqlgeometry

I'm trying to work with Entity Framework Core against a SQL Server database.

I've got a test class (based on Microsoft's demo 'blog/post' sample code) which I migrate to a SQL Server database.

I want to add a member to my test class which will save as a `SqlGeometry` column and allow me to read/write that data.

It doesn't seem that there is an appropriate geometry type in Entity Framework/ .NET Core - so how should I approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a workaround here, which will enable you to use this unsupported data type: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1100#issuecomment-286362657

Comment: Thise feels like (a very good) half solution in that I can write data to a SqlGeometry column. But I can't see how I can read that data back - since as far as I understand from this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) "SQL queries can only be used to return entity types that are part of your model." - and my Geometry point isn't a part of the model it's [NotMapped]

Comment: Correct, as noted in the sample code, you can use the column, but not read it directly, as there is no mapping available - why do you need to read it directly?

Comment: I'll be passing it out as text in a JSON object. And perhaps using it.  But I can just grab it with a SqlConnection and SqlCommand for now, until EF catches up.